# DRF How to use a Token to prove authentication

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to build an API. I am using Token Authentication. I get a valid token when requested. Then I call another API point to request data and send my Token. I do not appear to be authenticating. When I debug print to the server my user is Annonymous and my request.auth is None.

I am using Javascript in VueJS to make the call:

```js
    fetchHabits: function() {
      console.log('Token '+this.authToken.token);
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/habit/?format=json',{
         method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token '+this.authToken.token
      },

  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.habits = json)
  }
```

Can anyone please tell me how I pass a valid token to DRF so that it is recognized.
If I have to code it within a class, where is the valid token stored?

Thank you

Here are my Authentication classes. Notice the two commented out, unless they are commented out the api to send a username/password does not work:

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
         'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
 #        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
 #        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

     ), }
```

EFFECTS:
The objective is to send a username/pwd get a token, then do a request with that token.

```
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
#        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
#        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
#        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
```

Get Token, 500 Error Anonymous User (2nd part fails)

```
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
#        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
#        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
```

Get Token, 500 Error Anonymous User

```
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
#        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
```

Get Token, 500 Error Anonymous User

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
```

401 Unauthorized

With the help of @Rajan I have found that the Header has an unknown token (NOT in my database) and is returning Anonymous user, If I FORCE the token inline it works. But the current header authentication seems to not user the token I pass in the header but another one. Could it be being modified in the process?

Comment: have you configured the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES in settings.py for DRF

Comment: @rajan Updated to show you were I am at the moment in my settings. Also I have the installed apps:`    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
`

Comment: Please uncomment TokenAuthentication line.

Comment: @rajan when I do that my code to get the token fails. I get a 401 not authorized.

Comment: Then you need to apply AllowAny on the get_token request

Comment: So if you need to get your token you should give permission to anybody to access that view so that from where he can issue or get his token from Basic Authentication. And for rest of the views your Token Authentication will work.

Comment: I can get my token. I can reflect it in my console, and check it against the database. I am getting the correct token. However no other views seem to pick up the authentication. They show authentication=none user = AnonymousUser

Comment: You have to use sessionAuthentication if you want to reflect request.user in views. See [here](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/45)

Comment: @rajan, I added a debug tree on the various combinations, and showed which one got how far.

Comment: Try last config and do set Default_permission_class to     
    `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        )
    }`
This appears only to be permission issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149166/discussion-between-tony-sherman-and-rajan-chahan).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that the HTTP header was 'corrupt' I needed to put that the credentials were included. Final solution was:

```
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/habit/?format=json',{
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       'Accept': '*/*',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Token '+this.authToken.token
     },
     credentials: 'include'
  })
```